# Why is \d+ only matching one digit in this python regexp?

Tags: python, regex

Regexp: `editClassification/(?P<pk>[\d+])`

String to match: `foo/editClassification/10`

[pythex example](http://pythex.org/?regex=editClassification%2F(%3FP%3Cpk%3E%5B%5Cd%2B%5D)&test_string=foo%2FeditClassification%2F9%0Afoo%2FeditClassification%2F10&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: remove character class and use `(\d+)` instead

Comment: This usually comes up when people overuse character classes like `[\d]` or `[\s]`. Trying to expand, they get stumped and ask these questions that pop up here rather frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `\d+` is within a character class (`[...]`); `[\d+]` matches exactly one character that is either a digit or `+`.

You were supposed to write `(?P<pk>\d+)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your `\d+` was inside a *character class* (More info can be found at [Regexp Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) or the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)). This means any letter inside is selected. For example, `(a|b|c)` is equivalent to the character class `[abc]`. So your character class was matching either one digit, or a `+`.

You should remove the `[`square brackets`]` around the `\d+`. Your new RegEx:

```
editClassification/(?P<pk>\d+)
```

Alternatively, you could just move the `+` outside the character class, but that just wastes space.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Pythex**](http://pythex.org/?regex=editClassification%2F%28%3FP%3Cpk%3E%5Cd%2B%29&test_string=foo%2FeditClassification%2F9%0Afoo%2FeditClassification%2F10&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)</kbd>